# Listing methods of an object in Tcl

Tags: oop, tcl

How can I get all methods of an object in Tcl, preferably, from within a method, using the self command?
Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you're using TclOO, `self` doesn't do it; the `info` command has subcommands to do it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
info object methods [self]
```

gives all public method of this object.

```
info object methods [self] -all
```

also gives methods inherited from the object's class, and other classes or mixins.

```
info object methods [self] -private
```

lists private methods as well; can be combined with `-all`.

Documentation:
[info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm)